# When is the rank of the following matrix is 2.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Let $\sigma : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

$\sigma(x,y) = (x-x^3/3+xy^2,y-y^3/3+yx^2,x^2-y^2)$. I have to show that the differential of this function has rank 2, i.e.

$d\sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
1-x^2+y^2&2xy&2x\\
2xy&1-y^2+x^2&-2y\\
\end{bmatrix}$

I am not experienced solving such equations. Can you help me? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Obviously the rank is at least $1$. Can it really be $1$? What is the definition of rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a $3 \times 2$ matrix, but whatever. Take the right 2x2 minor. Its determinant is $-2x(x^2 + y^2 +1)$ which is $\neq 0$ for $x \neq 0$. If you put $x=0$, you only have to deal with the variable $y$ and you should be able to conclude